# Copiar un array de objetos en un archivo txt - Javascript

Tags: javascript, fs

Tengo una clase llamada Archivo, la cual dentro tiene un metodo que almacena articulos.

```js
class Archivo {
    constructor() {
        this.productos = [];
    }

    guardar(producto) {
        producto.id = this.productos.length + 1;
        this.productos.push(producto);
        async function guardar_producto() {
            try {
                await fs.promises.writeFile('./productos.txt', JSON.stringify([producto], null, '\t'))
                console.log('guardado')
            } catch (err) {
                console.log('error al guardar')
            }
        }
        guardar_producto()
    }
}
```

Quiero que estos objetos sean guardados en el archivo productos.txt destino del writeFile, pero solo logro que se guarde el primer objeto (lapicera).

```js
let articulo = new Archivo
articulo.guardar({
    title: 'Lapicera',
    price: 100,
    thumbnail: 'http://www.google.com.ar'
}, {
    title: 'Cartuchera',
    price: 150,
    thumbnail: 'http://www.google.com.ar'
}, {
    title: 'Lapiz',
    price: 50,
    thumbnail: 'http://www.google.com.ar'
})
```

Que puede estar pasando?

Comment: Prueba a escribir todo el objeto (y usa un array para encapsular todos los objetos): `fs.promises.writeFile('./productos.txt', JSON.stringify(this.productos, null, '\t'))` Solo se guarda uno porque literalmente es lo que estás haciendo al pasarle a la función varios objetos, si te das cuenta cuando usas el método lo haces del modo `({},{},...)` cuando creo que sería mejor hacerlo como array `([{},{},...])`.

Comment: lo intente, pero al momento de hacerlo la propiedad producto.id dentro del método guardar deja de funcionar... también lo he hecho con fs.append, que sería la forma en que logré que funcionara, pero me piden que sea con write

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema no está a la hora de guardar, sino a la hora de enviar los parámetros en articulo.guardar. El método guardar recibe un solo parámetro, y le estás enviando tres objetos, así que solo toma el primero. Es mejor guardarlo todo en un array y enviar producto por producto a la función con un ciclo for...in, tal que:

```
let articulo = new Archivo;
productos = [
{
    title: 'Lapicera',
    price: 100,
    thumbnail: 'http://www.google.com.ar'
}, {
    title: 'Cartuchera',
    price: 150,
    thumbnail: 'http://www.google.com.ar'
}, {
    title: 'Lapiz',
    price: 50,
    thumbnail: 'http://www.google.com.ar'
}
];
for (i in productos)
    articulo.guardar(productos[i]);
```

Lo hice así, y me funcionó perfectamente.

Comment: el problema es al revés, el recibe un objeto y solo lee el primer producto :/

Comment: @Christian Es que no está enviando un objeto, está enviando tres, por eso sólo recibe el primer producto, y el método guardar está construido para manejar un producto a la vez. Hice el cambio con el ciclo for, y me funcionó perfecto

Comment: lo siento, ahora que lo veo bien tienes razón.

Comment: @christian Tranquilo, ahora con la acotación que te hice, queda más claro que la respuesta original que di